# Is there a countable basis for the finite complement topology on the natural numbers?

Tags: general-topology

I have the following question on a worksheet:
Consider the finite complement topology τf on N. Does this topology have a
countable base? If so give one such base and if not prove your claim.

Been trying to solve this for several hours but I have got nowhere. I think that there is no countable basis because it seems like to construct a basis you would need to take the entire topology, but I have no idea if that's right or how to show that.

Thanks

Comment: What's the cardinality of the collection of *closed* sets?

Comment: The collection of closed sets is uncountably infinite. I'm not sure how that helps though?

Comment: No. The closed sets are the finite subsets of $\Bbb N$. This collection is countable. So, the collection of open sets is countable as well.

Comment: Ah, thank you, I understand now.

Comment: Sorry, I did search before posting but at the time I was assuming it had an uncountable number of sets so that post didn't seem relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT:** Calculate how many finite subsets $\Bbb N$ has, and conclude the number of cofinite sets.